# Trigger a lambda based on Cloudformation stack update/complete events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have this usecase where I need to trigger a lambda every time my cloudformation stack updates/deletes. Cloudformation does not emit any cloudwatch metrics. Is there a way to get the cloudformation events to trigger a lambda. Any existing examples I can refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add reference your lambda function within the cloudformation script as a custom resource. You can then have the custom resource run (which executes your Lambda) on every update of the stack.

Basic syntax is:

```
MyCustomResource: 
  Type: "Custom::TestLambdaCrossStackRef"
  Properties: 
    ServiceToken:
      !Sub arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${LambdaFunctionName}
    StackName: 
      Ref: "NetworkStackName"
```

More information here:
[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html)

Comment: Worth noting it *won't* run on every update unless there's a change in that resource, which there won't be. I do something similar but use a macro to set the value of a parameter passed to the custom resource. The value generated by the macro is always different, so every time the template is run as an update, the custom resource is always invoked due to the changed parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

Configure an SNS Topic as a Notification Option in the CFT via https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-add-tags.html. Have your lambda be a subscriber to that topic.